# Can we obtain LRU (least recently used) page replacement algorithm in O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, operating-system

Can we obtain LRU (least recently used) page replacement algorithm in `O(1)` (i.e constant time)?

Please give the algorithm if possible.

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A doubly-linked list can implement a LRU queue with O(1) operations.  Used nodes can be unlinked from their old location, and relinked to the head of the queue, in constant time.

Note that, if you want to use it as a page replacement method, you will still need to figure out how to use the MMU stats to efficiently update the queue.

Comment: Nice answer , but just wanted to point out to the questioner that this method is not used practically by any OS because of the time constraints it imposes.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really care about the exact order pages have been used; what you want is a list of "not recently used" pages that you can kick out on demand.  Practically, you update your page replacement stats batch-style, using the MMU's page-access flags -- but note that a doubly-linked LRU queue *is* a practical datastructure for this purpose...

Comment: but to find out the used nodes we have to traverse through the liked list...that will take O(n) time.....correct me if i m wrong..

Comment: Yes, you need an operation per page.  But at this point you aren't doing strict LRU any more: the page-access statistics aggregate millions of uses.  Also, for a practical application, you don't need to check every page at the same time -- you can rotate through them in round-robin fashion.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question.  No, you don't need to traverse through the linked list.  You go directly to the appropriate entry in the page table (which is a random access table accessible in O(1) time), unlink the entry from the LRU queue (for a doubly linked list, this takes O(1) time), and relink it to the most-recently-used end (also in O(1) time).

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia there are [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) to several LRU page algorithms, including links with implementations. Options include:

- Linked list
- LRU-K
- ARC
- Hardware support